# Multiple accounts in Gnome Shell

Tags: gnome

I'm wanting to sync many accounts with Gnome Shell such as Gmail, Hotmail, Google+, TWitter, Tumblr, Facebook etc. I know how to add accounts via the settings menu, however the only options I have are Windows Live and Google accounts.

Is there a way to edit this so I can have notifiers in the status bar etc? Really stuck on this one!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Yea upgrade to 12.10 the Gnome Online Account in that supports way more other accounts too than just these two.